# Javers - How to drop and create Javers tables in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javers

How to create the Javers tables such as `jv_snapshot`, from scratch every time the Spring Boot Application is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JaVers creates its tables if they not exist and never drops them. There is no `create-drop` option like in Hibernate. For testing we recommend using in-memory db (H2) and running each test on a new and empty db instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be auto created.

See a demo here: 
https://github.com/yhjhoo/javers-demo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as I wanted to clear all the data from JaVers for every start of my Spring Boot application in my dev environment using `postgres`.

I set up in my `application.properties` as follow:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always
    continue-on-error: true
```

Since `initialization-mode` is now active, Spring boot will look at the file `data.sql` under `src/main/ressources` and run the SQL inside.

```
TRUNCATE jv_commit CASCADE;
TRUNCATE jv_commit_property CASCADE;
TRUNCATE jv_global_id CASCADE;
TRUNCATE jv_snapshot CASCADE;
```

Even if the tables don't exist, Spring Boot will still start thanks to the `continue-on-error` setting.